# Linked Server Connectivity Issues?

Tags: sql-server, instance, linked-server

My linked server was fine until now and i was selecting data using some join statement for filtering the but suddenly its returning following error. i cannot execute any query against my linked server.

**Linked server is still  available as i tried a TEST CONNECTION from server object and it was successful**

> Msg 65535, Level 16,State 1, Line 0
>
> Sql Server Interface:Error Loading Server/Instance Specified
>   (xfffffff)
>
> oledb provider sqlnc111 for linked server "MSNAC/MSDB5" returned an
>   error " A login time out expired
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online.

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nobody has made any configuration changes, your queries may be timing out because of a big data change. Try to, at least temporarily, set the following option:

```
USE Yourdatabase;
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 0;
GO

RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

If it goes fine with these settings, your queries were simply timing out because of the set limit. Experiment a bit with your queries, see what is an appropriate limit to put in this properties (leaving it to infinity isn't a good idea) and reconfigure once again.

NOTE: the number is in seconds.

To read up more on this issue, check the [documentation for remote query timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option).

Comment: i tried  select statement with  joins  and subquery. do u think tat will  put any trouble for the remote linked server

Comment: So it's working now? Don't forget to put a reasonable remote query timeout parameter and not leave it at _unlimited_ (0).
The fact that the query is coming from another server isn't that big of an issue - the execution itself shouldn't be much different then if it was executed on that server in the first place. However, more often then not, the network is an issue when querying a linked server.

Comment: the issues were still there, as this happened when i tried a join statement with my local database with the remote server, i thought that something might go wrong that way

Comment: When dealing with a remote server and when you want to do something more with that data on your instance I suggest you pretty much do a `SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM RemoteServer.schema.Table`. Then do any joins or queries you want with a temporary table you created on your local server. This way you first pull the data and afterwards you're not dependent on that remote server or the network itself.

Comment: what can i do to bring it back. i do have access to four views and  its not executing anything   at all .. i am receiving the login and network related errors

Comment: To bring back what, the data from a remote server? You use a query like the one in my previous comment, select from remote server and bring all the data into a temporary table. If you're getting login errors, make sure the login which you added in the linked server options have access to the views you're trying to reach because the query on the linked server is being done in the context of that defined user.

Comment: I will keep it in  mind. now  we solved the issue, it was firewall who is doing the whole drama and now its corrected.  I was concerned as i thought it has something to do with database

Comment: wats the best way to  transfer records between databases , we are using a view and this willl fetch all the changes made there and will  import to our database.

Comment: @coffemug - you're pretty much spot on. As I already wrote, use a `SELECT ... INTO #tempTable FROM linkedServer.schema.TableOrViewName` and when you pulled all the data in a temp table on your server, do extra calculations if needed and then import the data from it to the database. You can even do all this within one transaction.